# maven-compiler-plugin explicity declared in all submodules

Tags: java, maven

I am working in a project which has over 10 submodules and every one of them has the explicit declaration.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The parent of these submodules is the same one that contains the submodules. Is there any advantage of doing this over putting it in the parent as

```
    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
               ....
        </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no advantage unless you anticipate changing your mind about this for only some of them.

Comment: and even then, you could override it module-by-module basis. So no advantage whatsoever I would say.